# Ajax call to API with parameter

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb

I have an api route per below:

```
apiRouter.get('/api/getCompTeams', function(req, res) {
var compTeams = Team.find({}, {competition: 1, team:1, _id:0} ).then(eachOne => {
  res.json(eachOne);
                    }, 
                      (fail)=> { 
                        console.log('Error!');
                      },
                    (proceed) => {
                    return compTeams;
                    });      
 });
```

This returns all teams in the Teams collection, with the below ajax call:

```
async function ajaxData(url) {
 var dataResults ;

 try {
    // AJAX CALL FOR DATA
    dataResults = await $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url, 
        dataType: 'json',
    }); //AJAX CALL ENDS

    return  dataResults;
 } // try ENDS

 catch (err) {
     console.log("error @ ajaxData");
     console.log(err.message);
 } // catch ENDS

}  // ajaxData ENDS
```

What I would like to do is to pass a parameter, with the ajax call, eg. 'La Liga', so that the apiRoute returns only teams with key:value that matches 'competition:La Liga'.  I have tried various options but none have succeeded.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Using NodeJS & MongoDB.

Mosiki.